# Having trouble understanding scope and variables using DOM in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I am working on a hangman game using Javascript only. It is for a class. I am new at Javascript and DOM so please be kind. At this point, I just want to print out SOMETHING, anything really, in my console log. I have been at it for days and hours removing all of my functions and game processes except the few shown here just to try to get something to work. My thought process is that variables that will not change within the loop and do not need to be dynamically updated in the html do not need to be properties of the hangman game. But, when I run the following code just to get something working to the console.log, I get userGuess is not defined. I thought I was defining it by assigning it the value of the keyUp event. If I make userGuess a property of the hangman game and then update all the rest of my code with hangmanGame.userGuess, I get all of these unexpected token errors.

Any thoughts?

```
//Variables===============================================================
var hangmanGame = {presidents: [
  "WASHINGTON",
  "ADAMS", 
  "JEFFERSON",
  "MADISON",
  "MONROE",
  "JACKSON",
  "VANBUREN",
  "HARRISON",
  "TYLER",
  "POLK",
  "TAYLOR",
  "FILLMORE",
  "PIERCE",
  "BUCHANAN",
  "LINCOLN",
  "JOHNSON",
  "GRANT",
  "HAYES",
  "GARFIELD",
  "ARTHUR",
  "CLEVELAND",
  "HARRISON",
  "MCKINLEY",
  "ROOSEVELT",
  "TAFT",
  "WILSON",
  "HARDING",
  "COOLIDGE",
  "HOOVER",
  "TRUMAN",
  "EISENHOWER",
  "KENNEDY",
  "NIXON",
  "FORD",
  "CARTER",
  "REAGAN",
  "BUSH",
  "CLINTON",
  "OBAMA"
], 

  wrongAllowed: 7,
  goodLetters: 0,
  wordArray: [],
  badArray: [], 
  wins: 0,

//functions=========================================================
  startGame: function() {
  var word = hangmanGame.presidents[Math.floor(Math.random() * hangmanGame.presidents.length)];
  },
}

  function write() {
    console.log("President" + word);
  }


//main process===============================
  document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toUpperCase();
  }

  if (userGuess == 'A'){
      write();
    }
```

Comment: Woah. Sorry about the formatting. This is my first stack post. I thought I indented it all before posting. I'm not sure what the first part of it is outside the code box?

Comment: I can't tell from your indenting but it looks like your `hangmanGame` object is not closed all the way

Comment: You've only defined userGuess as local variable so it is not visible outside this chunk of code document.onkeyup = function(event) {}. By simply adding userGuess as global var you will solve issue. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to this

```
// Main process
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toUpperCase();
  if (userGuess === 'A') {
    write();
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `word` defined at `write()` call?

Comment: @guest271314 `window.hangmanGame.startGame()`, if OP would return that variable in the method

Comment: @Daniel_L How does your Answer resolve Question? Is `word` defined in `write` function at your solution?

Comment: OPs question does not specifically address `word`

Comment: @Daniel_L _"OPs question does not specifically address `word`"_ ? Yes, OP's Question does specifically address `word`; see original Question at  _"At this point, I just want to print out SOMETHING, anything really, in my console log."_ `write` function: `function write() {
    console.log("President" + word);
  }`. Your Answer does not actually resolve issue described at Question, as `word` would still not be defined within `write` function?

Answer (score 0):

Include `if` statement within `keyup` event handler; `return` `word` variable from `handman.startGame` function, pass `word` to `write` function

```js
//Variables===============================================================
var hangmanGame = {
  presidents: [
    "WASHINGTON",
    "ADAMS",
    "JEFFERSON",
    "MADISON",
    "MONROE",
    "JACKSON",
    "VANBUREN",
    "HARRISON",
    "TYLER",
    "POLK",
    "TAYLOR",
    "FILLMORE",
    "PIERCE",
    "BUCHANAN",
    "LINCOLN",
    "JOHNSON",
    "GRANT",
    "HAYES",
    "GARFIELD",
    "ARTHUR",
    "CLEVELAND",
    "HARRISON",
    "MCKINLEY",
    "ROOSEVELT",
    "TAFT",
    "WILSON",
    "HARDING",
    "COOLIDGE",
    "HOOVER",
    "TRUMAN",
    "EISENHOWER",
    "KENNEDY",
    "NIXON",
    "FORD",
    "CARTER",
    "REAGAN",
    "BUSH",
    "CLINTON",
    "OBAMA"
  ],

  wrongAllowed: 7,
  goodLetters: 0,
  wordArray: [],
  badArray: [],
  wins: 0,

  //functions=========================================================
  startGame: function() {
    var word = hangmanGame.presidents[Math.floor(Math.random() * hangmanGame.presidents.length)];
    return word
  }
}

function write(word) {
  console.log("President " + word);
}


//main process===============================
var hangman = hangmanGame.startGame();


document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toUpperCase();
  if (userGuess == 'A') {
    write(hangman);

  }
}
```